# Direct url link to Modal popup (SimpleModal)

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

Is there a way to have a direct URL link to a modal popup using [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)?
What I mean is that if I go to that URL, the modal would be already popped up.

Answer (score 1):

In case you only want the modal to show when users come from a specific referring url, this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pathname = $(location).attr('href');
    if (pathname.indexOf("modalA") >= 0) {
        $('#modalA').show();
    }
});
```

and this for when you want different referring urls to open different modals:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pathname = $(location).attr('href');
    if (pathname.indexOf("modalA") >= 0) {
        $('#modalA').show();
    }
    else if (pathname.indexOf("modalB") >= 0) {
        $('#modalB').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#modalC').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the modal on load of the window.
As per the document your have provided, I think the following should work.
This code should be written in the document which URL you are going to open.

```
window.onload=function(){
$("#element-id").modal();
};
```